# Is it possible for Talend ESB to generate n amount of childjobs based on number of files in a directory path?

Tags: esb, talend

So - I have a child job, that I need to run on multiple files; the exact same child job. However, they need to be completely independent runtimes. For example, if I drop 1 file that takes 15 minutes to process int a directory, it will kick off the child job. If I drop another file that takes 1 minute to process into the same directory, it will kick off a second instance and run completely independent of the previously started child that is going to take 15 minutes to process.

Due to our environment and use case, I was told ESB would be a good fit for the solution, but I have found it doesn't seem to generate child jobs independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

This requires starting and running jobs in background mode, which is not possible inside talend. So we have to do it out of the box.

This requires building the actual job in standalone and calling it from a different job. To not process the same file twice, I'd move it into a process folder from the master job then process it in background mode.

**Linux:** 
We can do it through nohup. This can call the jobs async in background mode.  This only seems to be possible if we call nohup from a shell script.

**Windows:**
We can do it through start /b

Comment: But, if I schedule this job, if I drop 1 file in, it will kick off....and the job itself will become "locked". So if I drop another file in, it still won't pick up until the job becomes "unlocked" so to speak. Correct? I essentially have this with ESB, it locks at the file level, as opposed to the job level itself.

Comment: I basically need to spin up x amount of JVMs for the x amount of files I drop in a directory so they operate independently of one another.

Comment: I don't have an ESB studio handy to test this, but you can try with "Use an independent process to run subjob" option of the tRunJob component.

Comment: you're right. 1 file -> 1 job, and if during that it occumulates 10 files then the next execution will process 10 files.
Export your Talend job, do a tSystem: 
nohup myJob.sh --context_param file=process/file1.txt &
This runs the job in background, your actual process will come back and could pick the new file. Just make sure you have a process folder so the same file will not be picked twice.

Comment: So the nohup didn't seem to work. it spat out the following `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to nohup.out'`

Comment: and what do you have in nohup.out ?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of response, but I think I've got it. I took what you said about the tSystem and kind of ran with it, [Balazs Gunics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576196/balazs-gunics). However I had to make a slight modification. When initially using the tSystem to call the <child_job>.sh directly, it wouldn't return my session until that job was finished. So, in order to 'trick' Talend, I use the tSystem to call a simple little shell script that actually calls the <child_job>.sh. So now, when in an infinite loop, it can continue to pick up new files and execute them in isolation.

Comment: I rewrote the answer then, should I add anything more?